# Join tables to get the Id from table # 2 for each relevant/multiple row in table # 1 in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, join

There are 3 SQl server tables :
1. Table Account - all types of accounts and attributes - Rows- A= 123 B=456 C=789 ~ 3 accounts per customer, there can be multiple B and Cs for one customer

2. Table FlattenedHierarchy  - one column for each account type (A,B,C) to detail out the relationship - Column A= 123 B=456 C=789
3. Table subscriptions - Subscriptions and attributes for only one type of account i.e. C

I want to get the list of all account types = B that belongs to customer with corresponding Cs have active subscriptions. And the list of B's should also have corresponding A's listed, for the same customer there can be two B's, but both B rows should bring up the same A.

[Sample Tables and expected sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drvBk.png)

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Account t1
  LEFT JOIN `FlattenedHierarchy` t2 ON t1.AcctId=t2.B
  LEFT JOIN `Subscriptions` t3 ON t2.C=t3.Acct
  WHERE t1.AcctType='B' AND STR_TO_DATE(t3.`End Date`,'%c/%d/%Y') < CURDATE()
    AND t3.Acct IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i had tried different combinations of left joins but was not working for some reason. Thanks again.